# R is not reading my file correctly, it has three variables

Tags: r, csv, variables, import

I am trying to import data into R, the data set is of marriage rates. The data set has states, year (1990-2016), and the yearly rate. However it is not picking up the correct heading. Year is being converted to X.1,X.2,X.3 and so fourth. It is also attaching numbers to states for example Alabama is 1, I am not sure if that part can be fixed though.

Link to data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eLdPZKZBMDkoObl4tLemQSGTnhiAlvOT/view?usp=sharing

I've stripped the file for everything but the raw data and the heading year and state. This was after it was not reading my xslx file correctly so I converted to csv.

```
> csvfile<-read.csv(file="~/Desktop/datah.csv")
> csvfile
                  X   Year    X.1    X.2  X.3  X.4    X.5    X.6    
 X.7
1                 State 2017.0 2016.0 2015.0 2014 2013 2012.0 
2011.0 2010.0
2               Alabama    7.0    7.1    7.4  7.8  7.8    8.2    
8.4    8.2
3                Alaska    6.9    7.1    7.4  7.5  7.3    7.2    
7.8    8.0
4               Arizona    5.8    5.9    5.9  5.8  5.4    5.6    
5.7    5.9
5              Arkansas    9.5    9.9   10.0 10.1  9.8   10.9
```

I have shown what the first few results looks like.

Comment: skip the first row. ie include the parameter `skip =1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to skip the first line, as it doesn't contain your header:

```
My_data_frame <- read.csv(file="~/Desktop/datah.csv", skip = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

It's also a good approach to remove the **stringsAsFactors** automatic conversion.

I strongly recommend using dplyr afterwards, to tidy your data. It'll help you analyze it and plot it later if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your .csv file has a header, just tell this to R. Try:

```
csvfile<-read.csv(file="~/Desktop/datah.csv", header=T, sep=",")
```